# Print between two patterns

Tags: awk

How to print with awk between two patterns in a way that these two patterns will be on first and last line allone without other characters?

```
awk '
/\\caption/{
  next
}
/\\begin|word1/{
  found=1
}
found;
/\\end|word2/{
  found=""
}
' file.txt
```

file.txt:

```
text
\begin
gdgs
\end}
text
word1
gdflgk
gfdsg
word2
fg
```

The desired output:

```
\begin
gdgs
\end
word1
gdflgk
gfdsg
word2
```

Output now:

```
\begin
gdgs
\end}
word1
gdflgk
gfdsg
word2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ awk 'sub(/.*\\begin.*/,"\\begin"){f=1} f{ f=!sub(/.*\\end.*/,"\\end"); print}' file
\begin
gdgs
\end
```

Comment: Thank you and how to add another two patterns? I editted my qestion

Comment: That's made it a different question requiring a different answer. Put this question back the way it was, accept an answer, and then ask a new standalone followup question with your new sample input/output. If you have any other variants to address make sure to include those in your next question too, don't keep adding on requirements and updating a question.

Comment: OK, I write new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58673004/print-parts-of-file-using-awk thank you

Comment: You forgot to put this question back to how it was and accept an answer to that question.

Answer (score 1):

***EDIT:*** Since OP changed question a bit so adding solution as per it now.

```
awk '
/\\caption/{
  next
}
match($0,/\\begin/){
  found=1
  print substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)
  next
}
match($0,/\\end/){
  found=""
  print substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)
  next
}
found
match($0,/word1/){
  found_word=1
  print substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)
  next
}
match($0,/word2/){
  found_word=""
  print substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)
  next
}
found_word
'  Input_file
```

---

---

Could you please try following.

```
awk '
/\\caption/{
  next
}
match($0,/\\begin/){
  found=1
  print substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)
  next
}
match($0,/\\end/){
  found=""
  print substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)
  next
}
found
' Input_file
```

Comment: Your solution will shop of all text after `\begin` that are on the same line and before `\end` on the some line.  Try my test file.  This may/may not be ok for OP

Comment: @Jotne, It was written as per OP's  samples only sir.

Comment: That new script you added will print lines between `\\begin` and `word2`, etc.

Comment: @EdMorton, sure sir, I have edited my solution now. There could be more conditions on this one,but I kept it simpleby making different flags itself, I hope that corner case mentioned by you should be covered, cheers.

Comment: It'll still fail when the key words are interleaved, it'll fail when `\\end` or `word1` appears on a line of it's own without a preceding `\\begin`, etc., and it's not good practice having all that unnecessarily duplicated code.

Comment: @EdMorton, yeah I considered that, since samples were not having that condition so I haven't taken it in code, let me think about it and edit code, cheers.

Comment: The OP already wrote a new question for their real problem so not much point doing anything else with this one.

Answer (score 1):

This should do:

```
cat file
text
test\begin data
yes
gdgs
here we go
some\end}test
text

awk 'BEGIN {s="\\begin";e="\\end"} $0~"\\"e {split($0,a,"\\"e);print a[1]e;exit} f; $0~"\\"s {split($0,a,"\\"s);print s a[2];f=1}' file
\begin data
yes
gdgs
here we go
some\end
```

Trick part here is the `\` that do need to be escaped all the places. If it just was normal characters if wold be simpler. 
Trick here is that I split the line bye the start or stop tag and only take what I need after start or before stop.

Simpler to read:

```
awk '
  BEGIN {
    s="\\begin";
    e="\\end"}

  $0~"\\"e {
    split($0,a,"\\"e);
    print a[1]e;
    exit}

  f; 

  $0~"\\"s {
    split($0,a,"\\"s);
    print s a[2];
    f=1}
  ' file
```

If you just have `begin` and `end` without special characters, you could do:

```
awk 'BEGIN {s="begin";e="end"} $0~e {split($0,a,e);print a[1]e;exit} f; $0~s {split($0,a,s);print s a[2];f=1}' file
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Could you please comment your solution more? How to add next pattern? For instance between word1 and word2?

Comment: Thank you I write new question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58673004/print-parts-of-file-using-awk