# Print parts of file using awk

Tags: awk

I have several conditions for what I want to print (skip hello that is included in part I would like to print, print from \k{f} to \l{k}, from \word{g} to \word2{g}, print row starting \hello2 and print the part between \b and \bf - there is a problem: in \bf} is } that should not to be printed):

```
    awk '
/\\hello/{
  next
}
/\\k\{f\}|\\word\{g\}|\\b/{
  found=1
}
found;
/\\l\{f\}|\\word2\{g\}|\\bf/{
  found=""
}
/\\hello2/
' file.txt
```

I would like to add condition for \bf that it should be alone in the row. How to do that please?

file.txt:

```
text
text
\hello2
456
565
\word{g}
s
\hello
\word2{g}
\k{f}
fdsfd
fgs
\l{f}
text
\b
7
\hello
\bf}
text
```

Output now:

```
\word{g}
s
\word2{g}
\k{f}
fdsfd
fgs
\l{f}
\b
7
\bf}
```

The desired output:

```
\word{g}
s
\word2{g}
\k{f}
fdsfd
fgs
\l{f}
\b
7
\bf
```

This question is related to: [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58671993/print-between-two-patterns/58672279?noredirect=1#comment103647192_58672279)

Comment: Could you please add conditions more clearly in your question, like-->`I want to print from \k{f}  to `l{f}` etc? As it is not clear as of now.

Comment: I added it in my question

Comment: Please don't post chameleon questions, see https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/43478/361691.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a condition to replace \bf} with \bf

```
    awk '
/\\hello/{
  next
}
/\\k\{f\}|\\word\{g\}|\\b/{
  found=1
}
# Fix BF lines
/\\bf}/ { $0 = "\\bf" }
# 

found;
/\\l\{f\}|\\word2\{g\}|\\bf/{
  found=""
}
/\\hello2/
' file.txt
```

Comment: Thank you very much and could you help me with one more condition to this script?
I have line

`text text text \b text text 45 \bf`  text

How to print only `\b text text 45 \bf`

Comment: There's various possible inputs this would fail for, e.g. see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58671993/print-between-two-patterns#comment103648090_58672111 for some. @Archie - accepting the first answer you get is making the assumption that it's the best answer you could get as seeing an already accepted answer discourages others from posting alternatives. Also wrt `could you help me with one more condition` - see the advice I gave you about your previous question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58671993/print-between-two-patterns#comment103647126_58672418